# Django ORM groupby

Tags: django, orm

| row_1(PK) | row_2 | row_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | one |
| 2 | row | two |
| 3 | row | three |

Data from my database table looks like the above table.

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(row_3)
FROM table_
WHERE row_2 = 'row'
GROUP BY row_2;
```

My Django query to achieve above mysql query

```
table_.objects.filter(
    row_2='row'
).annotate(
    val=GroupConcat('row_3', '')
).values('val')
```

When converting the above ORM to raw mysql query, it's grouing by primary key (row_1). I want to group by 'row_2' column .

Comment: Your intended query is not valid SQL since a `GROUP BY` is part of the `SELECT`.

Comment: It is part of the SELECT.

Comment: `SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(row_3) FROM...`, there is no `row_2` in that clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`.order_by(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate), yes I know that sounds strange, so:

```
table_.objects.filter(row2='row').values('row2').annotate(
    val=GroupConcat('row3', '')
).order_by('row2')
```

But here it looks like you are actually making an *aggregate*, since only one sort of value for `row2` is picked due to the filtering, so grouping by that value is not necessary. You can use [**`.aggregate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) in that case:

```
table_.objects.filter(row2='row').aggregate(val=GroupConcat('row3', ''))
```

Comment: Hey Thank you. That worked. How can we put this inside a subquery!!